# How to select multiple columns using sum projection with group by in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, group-by, sum, projection

My MySQL query is:

```
SELECT 
    c.first_name, 
    c.middle_name, 
    c.last_name, 
    s.ticker, 
    COUNT(s.ticker), 
    SUM(t.cumulative_qty), 
    SUM(cumulative_balance)
FROM client_master c, security s, transaction_master t 
WHERE c.id = t. client_master_id AND s.id = t.security_id AND t.client_master_id = 4 
GROUP BY t.security_id;
```

This query returns an exact result. I want to write Hibernate Criteria that has a matching result. This is what I tried:

```
Criteria criteria = createEntityCriteria(TransactionDetails.class, "tr")
                .createAlias("tr.client", "cl")
                .createAlias("tr.security", "se")
                .add(Restrictions.eq("cl.id", clientId))
                .setProjection(Projections.sum("tr.cumulativeQty"))
                .setProjection(Projections.groupProperty("tr.securityId"));

return  criteria.list();
```

But this Criteria is returning just a `List` of `tr.securityId`. I want all the rows. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can not do `setProjection()` multiple times. You need to create a `ProjectionList` first and then set each projection. You also need to tell the criteria which fields you need in the resultset by specifying them in `Projections.property()` .

Try this:

```
ProjectionList projList = Projections.projectionList();
projList.add(Projections.sum("tr.cumulativeQty"));
projList.add(Projections.groupProperty("tr.securityId"));

projList.add(Projections.property("firstName"));
projList.add(Projections.property("lastName"));
//add other fields you need in the projection list

Criteria criteria = createEntityCriteria(TransactionDetails.class, "tr")
                .createAlias("tr.client", "cl")
                .createAlias("tr.security", "se")
                .add(Restrictions.eq("cl.id", clientId))
                .setProjection(projList);
```

Comment: Thank you for solution, I have done the changes suggested by you but it only returning Sum and securityId List instead of this I want all the columns e.g ( first_name, c.middle_name, 
c.last_name, s.ticker). Please Suggest the changes.

Comment: I just updated the answer, you need to use Projections.property("propertyName") to select all the properties.

Comment: I have just added two properties add the rest

Comment: Answer is perfect but this will not work with(onwards) mysql version 5.7.5, as it has new default as below -
ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
 you need to set sql_mode to below -
SET sql_mode='NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
Just change the sql_mode and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Also You could use multiple projection inline of a criteria. Like below.

```
Criteria criteria = createEntityCriteria(SomeClass.class)
           .createAlias(...some elias...)
           .add(Restrictions..... etc)
           .setProjection(
               Projections.projectionList()
                  .add(Projections.groupProperty("someProp1"))
                  .add(Projections.property("someProp2"))
                  .add(Projections.sum("someProp3"))
           );
```